# Extracting the descriptors of a bunch of sample images and training an SVM in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, svm, shapes, object-detection

I have 4 types of symbols of musical notes of the same color: Whole note, half note, Crotchet and quaver. I need to classify an image and tell if it has one of this symbols (just one for now) and which one. for example, if i have an image with just the musical staff (but nothing else in it) it should tell me that the image is empty, but if i have an image with a Half note symbol in it, it should tell me something like "it is a half note".

Suppose i have 20 sample images for each possible symbol and 20 with the base case (nothing in it), i want to train a SVM to classify any input image. I've read about how i could do it, but i still have certain doubts. i think the process is something like this (and please correct me if i'm wrong):

1. extract the descriptors of all the sample images.
2. put those descriptors inside different `Mat` Objects (one for each symbol).
3. feed those `Mats` to the SVM to train it.
4. Use the SVM to classify the images.

i have specific doubts about what i think is the process:

1. is what i described the correct process for what i need to do?
2. should i pre-process the sample images (say extract the background and apply canny edges) before i feed them to the descriptor extractor? o can i leave them as they are?
3. i have read about three methods of extracting the descriptors: HOG, BOW (Bag of Words) and SIFT. i think they all do what i need but i don't know which one to use. i see that HOG is mostly (if not all times) for face and pedestrians detection and i don't know if it could be used for my case. Any advice of which one should use?
4. how many sample images should i have for every case?

i dont need specific details of the implementation, but i do need answers to these questions, thank you in advance

Comment: you want a svm classifier to classify the 4 types of notes... I think it is a bit overhead to train a classifier for this easy task.. or I am missing sth ?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi well, what i need to do is detect via webcam kind of big notes that the user will stick on a 3mtx50cm staff that is glued to a wall and play the notes for certain amount of time depending on its shape. The notes wont always be straight, wont have always the same size (the camera could be closer or farther) and wont always receive the same illumination. So i thought this would be the best and more accurate approach. but if there is another approach for detecting the shapes that you can think of, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in your task you would not describe the whole image but only the desirdd object. so you would have some manual labeling work to perform.

Comment: sift would be combined with bow. hog would be combined with svm. both work very differently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert of SIFT and BOW but I know something about HOG and SVM.

**1 Is what i described the correct process for what i need to do?**
If you are using OpenCV and HOG no that is not correct. Have a look to the sample code for HOG in OpenCV samples and you will find that, once extracted, the descriptors directly feed the SVM without filling a MAT element.

**2 should i pre-process the sample images (say extract the background and apply canny edges) before i feed them to the descriptor extractor? o can i leave them as they are?**
This is not mandatory. Preprocessing has been proved to be very useful but for your simple case you wont need it. On the other hand, if your wall presents draws, stickers or something that can confuse the detector then yes. It can be a good solution to decrease the number of false positives.

**3 i have read about three methods of extracting the descriptors: HOG, BOW (Bag of Words) and SIFT. i think they all do what i need but i don't know which one to use. i see that HOG is mostly (if not all times) for face and pedestrians detection and i don't know if it could be used for my case. Any advice of which one should use?**
I have direct knowledge only of HOG. You can easily implement your own detector with HOG without any problem, I'm currently using it for traffic signs. Pay attention to the detection window that you want to use. You can leave all the other parameters as they are, it will work for simple cases.

**4 how many sample images should i have for every case?**
Once again it depends on the situation. I would say that 200 images (try also with less) for class will do the trick but you can always increase the number by applying some transformation on the positives. Try to flip, saturate or blur the images.

Some more considerations. I think that you can work with grey scale images due to the fact that color is not important to distinguish the notes (all the same color right?). If you have problem with false positives you can try to use the HSV color space to filter out patches that you will then use to detect the notes (it really works well with red!!). The easiest way to train your SVM is using a linear kernel and then train a model for each class.